# Proguard retrace.sh stack

Tags: android, proguard

I am struggling to understand debug information supplied by retrace.sh on my Android app. Why does it show 2 methods?

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mytaxicontrol.MyTaxiControlActivity$calctarif.java.lang.Void doInBackground$10299ca()(Unknown Source)
                                                     void nexttariflimit(boolean,boolean)
                                                     boolean newtaximoved(int,com.mytaxicontrol.MyTaxiControlActivity$nTW)
at com.mytaxicontrol.MyTaxiControlActivity$calctarif.java.lang.Object doInBackground(java.lang.Object[])(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lack of line numbers in the stack trace, ReTrace can't determine the original methods unambiguously, so it prints out all possible alternatives.

Cfr. ProGuard manual > ReTrace manual > [Examples](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/examples.html)

Cfr. ProGuard manual > Examples > [Producing useful obfuscated stack traces](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#stacktrace)

Comment: Hi, these links seem broken, they just take you to http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#

Comment: @scottyab The redirection seems to work in Firefox, but not in the current version of Chromium. I'll look into it.